# MySQL how to select with replacement of column with result of another query?

Tags: mysql, database, join, mariadb

So, i have a db.measurements that look like this

| Date | Value | equipement_id | operator_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-03-12 | 0.45 | 1 | 1 |
| 20-03-15 | 0.36 | 2 | 1 |
| 20-03-19 | 0.39 | 1 | 3 |
| 20-04-02 | 0.37 | 1 | 2 |

And a db.operators and db.equipements that look like this

| operator_id | operator_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mat |
| 3 | Brad |
| 4 | Alfred |

| equipement_id | equipement_model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Model-ABC |
| 2 | Model-XYZ |
| 3 | Model-SuperX |
| 4 | Model-Wifi |

So i need to do a query to select all the data from db.measurements but replacing the "id" of both equipement and operator with the respective name/model. What would be the best way to do it?
I can do `SELECT * FROM db.measurements;` but cant figure it out how to use REPLACE in this case since tables are longer.

Cant figure how join works. This query is not valid and returs nothing on mysql workbench

```
SELECT date, value, db.operators.operator_name as operator_name 
FROM db.measurements 
INNER JOIN db.operators ON db.operators.operator_id = operator_id;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join again with `db.equipements` the same way.

```
SELECT m.date, m.value, o.operator_name, e.equipement_model
FROM db.measurements AS m
INNER JOIN db.operators AS o ON o.operator_id = m.operator_id
INNER JOIN db.equipements AS e ON e.equipement_id = m.equipement_id
```